# Random order of rows when sorting is done on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a search page in which I am searching data by passing multiple parameters. I am using StartDate (Datetime field) as default sort order (result are sorted on the basis of StartDate if no sort order is provided). While searching I am getting random row order of data when multiple rows have same StartDate. 
Can anybody tell me what is the reason for this?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "default sort order"?  SQL Server does not have a default sort order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't explicitly define a sort order, there is no guaranteed order for the rows to be returned in.

If you `ORDER BY` a single field, the order of rows within groups that have a match on that field is indeterminate unless you define it.

I'm not sure what you expect to get back order-wise.  If you have an order you would like, **you must specify it** to get those rows in that order.

Period.

Comment: Thanks JNK for the reply, can you please provide me any link/ document which explains this behavior?

Comment: @AshwaniK [it's here on the ORDER BY page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx): `The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified.`

Comment: But here, we are specifying the order. If you can provide any link which explains the behavior when same values are encountered while using order by for a column, that will be very helpful.

Comment: You don't specify the order of the other fields.  You specify the order of a single field, but there is no guaranteed order for the other fields.